# Database (de)normalization - table with images for different entities

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, denormalization

I have a database schema which stores product images metadata and looks like this:

```
image_sizes (this is purely metadata - what sizes to create of given image, eg "thumb", "main image", "sidebar widget icon of the product", etc):
image_size_id (auto-increment, pk)
name (thumb, main)
max_width
max_height
crop (flag, to crop or just resize to fit)

images table:
image_id (auto-increment, pk)
image_size_id (fk to image_sizes)
image_batch_id (fk to batches, when there is uploaded image for the product, an image is created for each product size, all the images have same batch_id, described below)
location (relative path to the project eg uploads/products/thumbs)
width (result after processing, in pixels
height (result after processing, in pixels)
size (in bytes)

image_batches tables:
image_batch_id (auto-increment, pk)
product_id (fk, to which product it belongs)
original_filename (eg the file was called 123.jpg when uploaded)
is_default (if the product 10 images, one is default)
```

So this schema allows me to get all the "thumbnails" for a product for example and show them. Now the problem is that I want to have same schema for the users, or for other entities (there will be lets say venues as well) in the application.

Would it be appropriate if I modify the schema bellow, so that:

`image_batches` have additional column `image_type_id`. There will be `image_type` for `products`, `users`, `everything else that needs images`. And instead of `product_id` to have `entry_id` which for image_type `products` will be the product id, for image type `users` will be the user_id and so on.

I know this is denormalization that could lead to problems (if there is bug on the application side). But it seems like too much overhead if I need images for new type of entity to create set of 3 new tables to handle the same problem. Also that way there will be (kind of) code duplication on the application side as well.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, that would be using an database antipattern - the main problem being the lack of referential integrity, because you *won't* be able to define foreign keys on that table.

Long answer: The name of what you want to do is "polymorphic association". There are a few approaches to this:

**Solution A)** have two nullable columns: product_id and user_id

That is better than just having an entry_id, because you can define foreign keys. Your application only has to ensure that one (and only one) of those columns is NULL for every row in the image_batches table.

**Solution B)** have two intermediate tables: product_image_batches and user_image_batches which each reference your image_id

This will take the burdon of maintaining integrety off your application, and move it to your database, but introduces two new tables.